# API delete call for row from MySQL DB not work

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I'd like to create api call from back-end for DELETE query from mysql DB but when execute it in browser get error 
'Cannot GET ...'

I pass into the route id of row which had got from DB
At back-end the code is:

```js
app.delete('/products/delete/:id*?', function(req, res) =>{
let { id } = req.query;
    let DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_DB = `DELETE FROM my_db.products WHERE my_db.id= '${req.query}'`;
    console.log("id: ", req.query);
  // delete a row with id = req.query
    connection.query(DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_DB, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) return console.error(error.message);
    res.status(200).send(results);
    console.log("Deleted Row(s):", results.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

But finally this call not works and row not deleted

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to include the complete error message

Comment: Also try to execute your query directly on MySQL console to make sure it’s correct

Answer (score 0):

```js
let DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_DB = `DELETE FROM my_db.products WHERE my_db.id= '${req.query.id}'`;
console.log("id: ", req.query.id);
```

```html
Try using this.
```

```js
fetch(url, {
    method: 'delete'
}).then(response => response.json());
```

```html
Try running this in your browser console. It should work.
```

Most likely you're making a GET call to a DELETE resource.
Please read [Express 4.x](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.delete.method). Can you share the code you're using to make DELETE request from browser?

Comment: just simple following on url

http://localhost:4000/products/delete/5

where 5 is test_id

I understand that this is different method of http request but when I run call for adding items

http://localhost:4000/products/add?product_name=fakename&sku=54&price=200&is_active=1

(and this is POST method)

it works

I use Node.js for back and front on React

Comment: Please change your rest call to DELETE type. Backend api won't accept GET request. Are you using AJAX for making call or any other framework?

Comment: You can use POSTMAN for simulating network calls(PUT/DELETE etc.) and testing web api. By Default browser makes a GET request from search bar when you hit enter. Can you share the backend code for POST api you mentioned?

Comment: I use only the code provided in a question to execute this request

Comment: in the console I have

Products server listening on port 4000
id:  {}
id:  {}
Deleted Row(s): 0

It looks like id can't be extracted from DB. Will try then fix this.

Thank's for the pointing onto the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes and now running version of the code looks like

```
app.delete('/products/delete/:id', (req, res) => {
  let { id } = req.params ;
  let DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_DB = `DELETE FROM my_DB.products WHERE id= '${id}'`;
  console.log('id: ', req.params);
  // delete a row with id = req.params
  connection.query(DELETE_PRODUCT_FROM_DB, (error, results, fields) => {
    if (error) return console.error(error.message);
    res.status(200).send(results);
    console.log('Deleted Row(s):', results.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Also, I figured out that changes from `req.query` on `req.params` helped to get id from the link as a parameter